# crontab doesn't execute 'ioreg' on my mac

Tags: macos, bash, shell, cron

I would like track my battery information on my mac, 
So I assign a script file to crontab but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
#getbattery.sh
CURRENT_CAPACITY=$(ioreg -l -n AppleSmartBattery -r | grep CurrentCapacity | awk '{print $3}')
MAX_CAPACITY=$(ioreg -l -n AppleSmartBattery -r | grep MaxCapacity | awk '{print $3}')
CHARGE=$(echo $CURRENT_CAPACITY $MAX_CAPACITY | awk '{printf ("%i", $1/$2 * 100)}')
echo "$CHARGE""%  $(date) "
```

-

```
#my crontab content:
*/1 * * * * ~/getbattery.sh >> ~/batteryinfo.txt
```

Why **ioreg** doesn't work in the crontab?
Please tell me what happen if anybody knows my problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cron jobs run with a very minimal environment, including a very basic PATH (just /usr/bin:/bin). But ioreg is in /usr/sbin, so it won't be found as a command based on that PATH. There are three easy solutions:

1. Set the PATH in your crontab:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
   */1 * * * * ~/getbattery.sh >> ~/batteryinfo.txt
   ```
2. Set the PATH in your script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #getbattery.sh
   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
   CURRENT_CAPACITY=$(ioreg -l -n AppleSmartBattery -r | grep CurrentCapacity | awk '{print $3}')
   # etc...
   ```
3. Use an explicit path for ioreg (and any other commands not in /bin or /usr/bin) in your script :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #getbattery.sh
   CURRENT_CAPACITY=$(/usr/sbin/ioreg -l -n AppleSmartBattery -r | grep CurrentCapacity | awk '{print $3}')
   # etc...
   ```