# Sheduling start rails server after rebot with .sh script "script.sh: line 2: rails: command not found" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, ubuntu

I tried to automatically run my Rails server after a server reboot. I use `cronetab` that refers to file with scripts.
I have a problem with file.sh execution.
In this file I

```
#!/bin/bash
cd MyApp/ && rails s
```

redirect to app folder and try to run command to run the server.
I try to do a test run by launch script from bash
`/directory/to/script/file.sh`
but all i got is
`/directory/to/script/file.sh: line 2: rails: command not found`

When I run `cd MyApp/ && rails s` in bash directly everything works just fine.

Can you please help me. I need to automate starting rails server after rebooting. 
System => Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: 3 Suggestions :What's the absolute path of MyApp/.U should use absolute path in your script.Use `pwd` after  `cd` to see where you are, it's probably a path's problem.

Comment: `rails` apparently isn't in the default `PATH` for cron jobs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622613/crontab-doesnt-execute-ioreg-on-my-mac/) for a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys.

In the end, the answer was already on Stack "[Start rails server automatically when ever I start my ubuntu machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563714/start-rails-server-automatically-when-ever-i-start-my-ubuntu-machine)" but not the best-score answer was right :)

I dump idea with external script and pack everything to crontab

`@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /full/path/MyApp && rails s'`